# Find and replace text file Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, replace, find

I'm writting a Matlab code that generates an array number and it should replace that each number in a text file (that already exists) and replace all instances with that. The number should be in string format. I've achieved this:

```
ita='"';
for i=1:size(z,2)
word_to_replace=input('Replace? ','s');
tik=input('Replacement? ','s');
coluna=input('Column? ');
files = dir('*.txt');
for i = 1:numel(files)
    if ~files(i).isdir % make sure it is not a directory
        contents = fileread(files(i).name);
        fh = fopen(files(i).name,'w'); 
        val=num2str(z(i,coluna));
        word_replacement=strcat(tik,val,ita);
        contents = regexprep(contents,'word_to_replace','word_replacement');
        fprintf(fh,contents); % write "replaced" string to file
        fclose(fh) % close out file
    end
end
end
```

I want the code to open the file#1 ('file.txt'), find and replace all instances 'word_replacement' with 'word_to_replace' and save to the same file. The number of txt files is undefined, it could be 100 or 10000.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the following statement:

```
contents = regexprep(contents,'word_to_replace','word_replacement');
```

You are using regular expressions to find any instances of `word_to_replace` in your text files and changing them to `word_replacement`.  Looking at your code, it seems that these are both **variables** that contain strings.  I'm assuming that you want the **contents** of the variables instead of the actual name of the variables.

As such, simply remove the quotations around the second and third parameters of `regexprep` and this should work.

In other words, do this:

```
contents = regexprep(contents, word_to_replace, word_replacement);
```